# How to get if user enable the any permission from settings page of app in android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-permissions, onactivityresult, application-settings

How to get if user enable the permission from setting page of application

For Example
Consider a app has permission activity. In permission activity it show location permission default dialog. when user allow the permission I proceed the further steps. When user denied the permission, Then I show the permission dialog again. When user permanently denied. I redirect to app settings page using below code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
intent.setData(uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

How to get If user enable the particular permission from the settings page of app like get result from Activity Result.

Comment: You just check again to see if you have the permission at the appropriate time (e.g., when the user clicks the button that is for some functionality that needs the permission).

Comment: What I am Looking is to update the UI When user enable the permission from the settings page

Comment: You do not have a good way to know when that occurs. This is particularly true in cases where multiple apps may be visible at once (split screen, Chrome OS's freeform multi-window, foldables, tablets running Android 12L and higher, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

The application details settings intent does not provide any activity result.

You need to keep track of what permissions were granted before starting the details settings intent and comparing that to what permissions are granted when your activity resumes.

To do this, you can use [checkSelfPermission](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/ContextCompat#checkSelfPermission(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String))

Comment: how to get whether the app is resumes from settings page??

Comment: @SumanRadhakrishnan even I have the same issue, I dont want to just have some code in onResume which gets called everytime. Just want to handle whe user is back from settings page